# Boost.asio & UNIX signal handling

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals, boost-asio

### Preface

I have a multi-threaded application running via Boost.Asio. There is only one `boost::asio::io_service` for the whole application and all the things are done inside it by a group of threads. Sometimes it is needed to spawn child processes using fork and exec. When child terminates I need to make waitpid on it to check exit code an to collect zombie. I used recently added `boost::asio::signal_set` but encountered a problem under ancient systems with linux-2.4.* kernels (that are unfortunately still used by some customers). Under older linux kernels threads are actually a special cases of processes and therefore if a child was spawned by one thread, another thread is unable to wait for it using `waitpid` family of system calls. Asio's signal_set posts signal handler to `io_service` and any thread running this service can run this handler, which is inappropriate for my case. So I decided to handle signals in old good signal/sigaction way - all threads have the same handler that calls `waitpid`. So there is another problem:

### The problem

When signal is caught by handler and process is successfully sigwaited, how can I "post" this to my `io_service` from the handler? As it seems to me, obvious `io_service::post()` method is impossible because it can deadlock on `io_service` internal mutexes if signal comes at wrong time. The only thing that came to my mind is to use some pipe or socketpair to write notifications there and `async_wait` on another end as it is done sometimes to handle signals in `poll()` event loops.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: This would also be the only think I can think of. I feel your pain for having to support ancient Linux 2.4.

Comment: The only other thing I think of is to structure your code so that only 1 thread is responsible for doing the forks, possibly by having it's own io_service that gets posted to do the fork.

Comment: Thank you, it appeared to be cleaner to have distinct thread for spawning/reaping children with its own io_service that waits for signals and performs packaged_tasks for spawning children. Maybe it is worse from performance point of view but the code is cleaner and still uses only boost signal handling, no old-school handlers made only of async-signal-safe function calls.

Answer (score 2):

I've not dealt with boost::asio but I have solved a similar problem.  I believe my solution works for both LinuxThreads and the newer NPTL threads.

I'm assuming that the reason you want to "post" signals to your *io_service* is to interrupt an system call so the thread/program will exit cleanly.  Is this correct?  If not maybe you can better describe your end goal.

I tried a lot of different solutions including some which required detecting which type of threads were being used.  The thing that finally helped me solve this was the section titled *Interruption of System Calls and Library Functions by Signal Handlers* of man signal(7).

The key is to use **sigaction()** in your signal handling thread with out **SA_RESTART**, to create handlers for all the signals you want to catch, unmask these signals using **pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, sig_set, 0)** in the signal handling thread and mask the same signal set in all other threads.  The handler does not have to do anything.  Just having a handler changes the behavior and not setting **SA_RESTART** allows interruptible systems calls (like **write**()) to interrupt.  Whereas if you use **sigwait()** system calls in other threads are not interrupted.

In order to easily mask signals in all other threads.  I start the signal handling thread.  Then mask all the signals in want to handle in the main thread before starting any other threads.  Then when other threads are started they copy the main thread's signal mask.

The point is if you do this then you may not need to post signals to your *io_service* because you can just check your system calls for interrupt return codes.  I don't know how this works with boost::asio though.

So the end result of all this is that I can catch the signals I want like SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGHUO and SIGQUIT in order to perform a clean shutdown but my other threads still get their system calls interrupted and can also exit cleanly with out any communication between the signal thread and the rest of the system, with out doing anything dangerous in the signal handler and a single implementation works on both LinuxThreads and NPTL.

Maybe that wasn't the answer you were looking for but I hope it helps.

NOTE: If you want to figure out if the system is running LinuxThreads you can do this by spawning a thread and then comparing it's PID to the main thread's PID.  If they differ it's LinuxThreads.  You can then choose the best solution for the thread type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already polling your IO, another possible solution that is very simple is to just use a boolean to signal the other threads.  A boolean is always either zero or not so there is no possibility of a partial update and a race condition.  You can then just set this boolean flag without any mutexes that the other threads read.  Tools like valgrind wont like it but in practice it works.

If you want to be even more correct you can use [gcc's atomics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) but this is compiler specific.